# How to publish an Android app from Android-Studio using a Keystore file generated in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have already published my App in Google-Play two years ago. At that time, I was using `Eclipse` to generate the `keystore` file (which is then kept save for future `APKs` generation) to export my App.

Now, I want to migrate to `Android-Studio`, mainly because it is much simpler to work with `Git` and `Veriosn-Control`.

Before migrating though, I want to make sure that I can continue creating new versions of the `APK` each time I want to update the App online in Google-play using `Android-Studio`.

I just want to ask if is it possible ?! and if the answer is 'Yes', how can I export my app from `Android-Studio` using the 'keystore' file I was using before for exporting the app from `Eclipse` ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What matters here is `keystore` file only. If you keep the keystore file you used with Eclipse then all you need to do is keep using it with Android Studio as keystore is pure Java thing and is IDE independent (in fact IDEs are just using the keystore but you can also play with them using [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) alone). And in fact you must use the same key for further updates of your Play Store released apps otherwise you will not be able to publish them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking that the `keystore` file is an IDE dependant. But now I'll migrate to `Android-Studio` with confidence. I have the `keystore` file stored in a save location. I will try to migrate to Android-Studio and use it to create a new APK for the same application and see  ... fingers crossed !!